# Visual Studio Code, launch.json, How-to dynamically generate a date time string in program arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to debug a Python script in Visual Studio Code.
One of the arguments is the output directory which needs to be changed with every execution of the script.
I want to automatically add a suffix to the output directory argument like below. /some/path_<date_time>
I tried playing with environment variables, but I thought there must be a simpler way I am not aware of. Any hints are appreciated.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "TEST",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "args": [
            "--outdir /some/path_$(date_time)"
        ]
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#datetime) and the command `extension.commandvariable.dateTime`

You need to use an `${input:__id__}` variable.

an example from the README (link)

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo date",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [ "${input:shortDate}" ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "shortDate",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.dateTime",
      "args": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "options": {
          "year": "numeric",
          "month": "2-digit",
          "day": "2-digit",
          "hour12": false,
          "hour": "2-digit",
          "minute": "2-digit",
          "second": "2-digit"
        },
        "template": "${year}/${month}/${day}-${hour}:${minute}:${second}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Modify the `template` property to suite your need.

Comment: Have you tried this with launch.json? 
I added the inputs section in my launch.json as above. and called my script with the variable. The variable was not evaluated.
It is also strange that the variable in this example is called with input and defined with input(s). Looks like a spelling error.

Comment: {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
....
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "mypthon_script.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": [
                "${inputs:shortDate}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: command 'extension.commandvariable.dateTime' not found

Comment: works now! thanks!
I installed the extension "Command Variable"

Comment: @brane you can now delete the comments, they have no purpose anymore